# Angular Custom Validation With Username Param And If Else - Control Not Working

Tags: angular

I've been trying to get the following custom validator to work.  It checks the database to see if the user entered a unique username but always errors of various kinds.  I've moved the "control: AbstractControl" line of code around including above the http service call but still errors.  The service works fine and returns the user name object such as user_name: "preston".

I suspect the problem is that I don't have a mental map of how to work with form controls and most of the info online doesn't include reaching out to a db and then a conditional.  I also suspect that I'm mixing the form controls concept with a plain old form event interaction method and this fails.  How do I fix this mess?

Part of the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="addEditMemberForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addEditMemberForm.value)"
        [class.error]="!addEditMemberForm.valid && addEditMemberForm.touched">

    <mat-form-field class="inputBackground">
          <input matInput #userName maxlength="30" class="inputField"    
              type="text" id="user_name"formControlName="user_name" 
              [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required
              (blur)="validateUsername(userName.value)">

          <mat-hint align="end">{{userName.value?.length || 0}}/30</mat-hint>

          <div class="formError" 
            *ngIf "this.addEditMemberForm.controls['user_name']
                .hasError('alreadyExist')">
                This username already exists in our database</div>

          <mat-error>{{ errors.required }}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

On the component:

```
private createForm() {
    this.addEditMemberForm = this.fb.group({
    ...
    user_name: ['', Validators.required, this.validateUsername()],
    ...
}

 private validateUsername(userName) {
   this.httpService.validateUsername(userName)
    .subscribe(res => {
      const convertedName = res['user_name']; // Convert from object to string.

        if (convertedName === userName): ValidatorFn {
          console.log('res if: ', res);
          // return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
          return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
            return {'alreadyExist': true};
          };
        }
        return null;  // This result means that the user name isn't taken and do nothing.
      },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.error);
          console.log(err.message);
        }
    );
 }
```

Comment: `addEditMemberForm` sounds like candidate for `memberForm` only ;)

Comment: Yeah.  As I learn coding and laying out the app there are artifacts everywhere :-)  Thanks for pointing out this one.  This app started in Python, moved to Angularjs, and then Angular, and then to reactive.  Then several major refactorings as I learned Angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
user_name: ['', Validators.required, this.validateUsername().bind(this)],\
```

and

```
  private validateUsername(control: AbstractControl) {
    const val = control.value;
    return this.httpService.validateUsername(val).pipe(
      map(res => {
        const convertedName = res['user_name'];
        return convertedName === val ? { alreadyExist: true } : null;
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.error);
        console.log(err.message);
        this.messagesService.openDialog('Error aef-2', 'Database not available.');
        return Observable.of({ "error": true })
      })
    );
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries-jgr5cj?file=app/members/add-edit-form/add-edit-form.component.ts

Obviously this may not work as I dont know how your service work nor what kind of response i will provide. But service is called on user input and thats fine. You only need to add `catchError` to the pipe to handle exceptions and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

@Antoniossss has a workable answer to my original question and he was very helpful guiding me to understand how this works.  However, if you use .bind(this) then there is a server call with every letter typed by the user, like incremental search.  This can get ugly if you check your server and console logs.

At the time of this post the Angular form control updateOn: 'blur' has a pull request to add it to FormGroup's.  It doesn't work as of 6/26/2018.  This may make @Antoniossss's solution the better choice.

I refactored his code and after many experiments found a solution.  A more elegant solution would be good.

[Stackbliz with code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries?file=app%2Fmembers%2Fadd-edit-form%2Fadd-edit-form.component.ts)

The html.  Notice the simple *ngIf. If the bound var is true then show the message.

```
    <li>
        <label class="label-pad">User name: </label>
        <mat-form-field class="inputBackground">
          <input matInput #userName maxlength="30" 
                 class="inputField" type="text" id="user_name"
                 formControlName="user_name" 
                 [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required 
                 (blur)="validateUsername(userName.value)">

          <mat-hint align="end">{{userName.value?.length || 0}}/30</mat-hint>

          <div class="formError" *ngIf = "this.inDatabase === true">
            This username already exists in our database</div>

          <mat-error>{{ errors.required }}</mat-error>

        </mat-form-field>
    </li>
```

The component.  When the form is created no custom validator and no binding. Binding kills the blur in the html.  It had to go.  Blur calls a function when the user leaves the field and passes the value of the field.  The function called gets the correct object from the db, only one call, and extracts the user name string.  Then it tests the condition and if there is a match then it calls another function to deal with the controls, display and clears the message with setTimeout, and clears the field which sets it back to invalid.  Then the user tries again.  Of course this should be in a service but I'll keep it simple here.  The Stackbliz code changes frequently so it may be in a service someday.

```
...

public inDatabase = false; // Form validation - userName taken...

...

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private messagesService: MessagesService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }


  // The reactive model that is bound to the form.

  private createForm() {
    this.addEditMemberForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      first_name: ['', Validators.required],
      last_name: ['', Validators.required],
      user_name: ['', Validators.required],
      country: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  private validateUsername(userName) {
      return this.httpService.validateUsername(userName)
      .subscribe(res => {

        const extractedName = res.map(x => x.user_name); // array

        // Convert from array to string.
        const convertedName = extractedName.toString(); 

        // If the condition is met then call the isTaken function below.
        return convertedName === userName ? this.isTaken() : null;
      },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.error);
          console.log(err.message);
          this.messagesService.openDialog('Error', 'Delete did not happen.');
        }
      );
  }

  public isTaken() {
    this.inDatabase = true;  // Var is bound to html conditional.

    // Remove the already in database message after some time.
    setTimeout (() => {
      this.inDatabase = false;
    }, 2000);

    // Clear the field to reset validation and prepare for next attempt.
    this.addEditMemberForm.controls['user_name']
      .setValue(null);
  }
```